# c++ when using functions function call missing argument

Tags: c++, class

```
void Circle::getXYr() {
    cout << "(x,y,R) = (" << x << "," << y << "," << r << ")" << endl;
}

double Circle::circArea() {
    return (r * r * PI);
}

double Circle::circPeri() {
    return (2 * r * PI);
}

void Circle::printCircle() {
    cout << "Printing circle " << getXYr << endl;
    cout << "Circle Area: " << circArea << endl;
    cout << "Circle Perimeter: " << circPeri << endl;
}
```

I cant use the printCircle function: ERROR Error    1   error C3867: 'Circle::getXYr': function call missing argument list; use '&Circle::getXYr' to create a pointer to member

also the same for the next 2 functions.

Comment: cout << "Printing circle " << getXYr() << endl;

Comment: You are missing parenthesis after the 'function call' in the cout-statements. You should add `()` behind your function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It are functions, you have to call them as such. Note the brackets `()`

```
cout << "Printing circle " << this->getXYr() << endl;
cout << "Circle Area: " << this->circArea() << endl;
cout << "Circle Perimeter: " << this->circPeri() << endl;
```

`this->` is not explicitly needed.

Your second error is due this->getXYr() does not return a value. It returns `void`. There is no basic_ostream overload for it.

You either should put the logic of the getXYr() into the printCircle() function. Or call that function without calling cout on it:

```
cout << "Printing circle ";
this->getXYr();
cout << "Circle Area: " << this->circArea() << endl;
cout << "Circle Perimeter: " << this->circPeri() << endl;
```

Comment: getXYr is still giving me an ERROR:  2 IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands
            operand types are: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> << void

Comment: I actually managed to fix getXYr by doing it in another line.         for some reason that I dont know I cant use this function with cout.

Comment: Well like I said, your trying to print the return output of getXYr(). But this function is not returning anything. See updated answer.